# Polymer 2: Polymer build - error

Tags: polymer

I finished my project in polymer 2, and i tried to execute "polymer build" command but it returns me this error: Promise rejection: Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/Users/tech387/Desktop/Wobbl/Wobbl-Frontend-Admin-Console/bower_components/bower_components/polymer/polymer-element.html'

It seems it tries to find my polymer element in wrong directory because my polymer element is in this path:'/Users/tech387/Desktop/Wobbl/Wobbl-Frontend-Admin-Console/bower_components/polymer/polymer-element.html'.

The problem is that first path contains .../bower_components/... twice and I dont know how to delete one so that path would match polymer element destination. Does anyone knows how to do that?

Comment: try to use local path for the polymer-element import. Specify the path of the build command and then go for it.

Answer (score 1):

The root cause of this problem is wrong path being mentioned as part of href.
For example 


If actual path was one of the above and there happens to be a mistake with "../".
Promise rejection occurs. Though error is misleading problem occurs main due to this reason.
A more clear explanation can be found here:
https://github.com/Polymer/polymer-analyzer/pull/801